# Typesafe perfect binary tree in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to implement typesafe [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) in Scala. In other words the following should compile:

```
 Succ(Node(Leaf("a"), Leaf("b")))
 Node(
   Succ(Node(Leaf("a"), Leaf("b"))),
   Succ(Node(Leaf("c"), Leaf("d"))))
```

but the following should not:

```
 Node(
   Succ(Node(Leaf("a"), Leaf("b"))),
   Leaf("c"))
```

I came up with the solution below that satisfies the above but one can trick the compiler:

```
Node(
   Leaf("f"): PerfectBinaryTree,
   Succ(Node(Leaf("a"), Leaf("b"))): PerfectBinaryTree)
```

Is there a way to avoid even that in Scala? 
How is it different from Haskell (if at all)?

```
trait PerfectBinaryTree {
    type N <: PerfectBinaryTree
  }

  case class Succ[P <: PerfectBinaryTree](p: P) extends PerfectBinaryTree {
    type N = Succ[P]
  }

  class Leaf[T] private (t: T) extends PerfectBinaryTree {
    type N = Leaf[T]
  }

  object Leaf {
    def apply[T](t: T): Leaf[T] = new Leaf(t)
  }

  case class Node[A <: PerfectBinaryTree, B <: PerfectBinaryTree](l: A, r: B)(implicit evidence: A =:= B) extends PerfectBinaryTree {
    type N = A
  }
```

Comment: You have two questions in your question. I suggest you remove any reference to Haskell in this question and eventually ask a related question on implementing this in Haskell.

Comment: In Haskell, this would be `data PerfectBinaryTree a = Zero a | Succ (PerfectBinaryTree (BinaryNode a))` and `data BinaryNode a = Node a a`. You seem to have messed up this structure in your Scala code. Is `Leaf` supposed to be `Zero`? And why are they are all cases of the same class?

Comment: Quite possible @Bergi that I messed it up. Yeah `Leaf = Zero`. 
How to arrange it back? ;)
I will consider this @Bakuriu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick (just like in Haskell) is to pass `Node` inside the type variable ([polymorphic recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_recursion)).

The definition of the classes then becomes very simple

```
case class Node[+A](left: A, right: A);

sealed trait Tree[+A];
case class Succ[+A](subtree: Tree[Node[A]]) extends Tree[A];
case class Leaf[+A](value: A) extends Tree[A];
```

(of course you'd want to add functions for folding/traversing such a tree etc.)

Then, when creating values, the amount of `Succ` constructors determines how many `Node`s need to be at the leaf. Notice that there is always just a single leaf, but it then contains a binary tree composed of the given number of `Node` levels:

```
val sample: Tree[String] =
 Succ(
  Succ(
    Leaf(
      Node(
        Node("a", "b"),
        Node("c", "d")
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Wow! Is there some good source of such knowledge available out there ?

Comment: @mjaskowski There are research papers on the topic. See for instance how to enforce [type safe red black trees in Java](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/smk/redblack/rbj.pdf). You may also want to search for the  previous paper by Ralf Hinze on the topic  "Constructing Red-Black Trees".

Comment: @mjaskowski I'd also suggest to read the famous Okasaki's book _Purely Functional Data Structures_ (the original thesis is available online). In particular there is a chapter "Structural Decomposition" that talks about this. In general, polymorphic recursion is a nice trick and it's worth exploring it. Another good pointer would be to study the correspondence between the representation of natural numbers and data structures, also in the same book. In this case, we'd represent powers of two.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @PetrPudlák! Here is a link: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf